# Java Generics: lower bound, can add an object to a list using Arrays.asList but not using List.add

Tags: java, generics

Trying to add "hello" to List with lower bound of a Number.

This does not work (as expected):

```
List<? super Number> numList = new ArrayList<>();
numList.add(1);
numList.add(3.0);
numList.add("hello"); // <--- fails here with ('add(capture<? super java.lang.Number>)' in 'java.util.List' cannot be applied to '(java.lang.Object)')
```

This works (why does it work?):

```
List<? super Number> numList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3.0, "hello");
```

Note: the numList is lower bounded by Number and "Hello" is a String.

Comment: Why shouldn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because Arrays.asList() returns a List of Serializables "and 'hello' is serializable" so no problem there

so this

```
List<? super Number> numList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3.0, "hello");
```

is like

```
List<? super Number> numList = new ArrayList<Serializable>();
```

which is acceptable at compile time because Number implements Serializable.

to make it not work you need to tell Arrays.asList() to return List of Numbers like this

```
List<? super Number> numList = Arrays.<Number>asList(1, 2, 3.0, "hello");
```

---

**Edit:**

Arrays.asList(). what happens behind the scenes is 'from docs'

> Java compiler looks at each method invocation and corresponding declaration to determine the type argument (or arguments) that make the invocation applicable. The inference algorithm determines the types of the arguments and, if available, the type that the result is being assigned, or returned. Finally, the inference algorithm tries to find the most specific type that works with all of the arguments.

you can find more examples [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html)

Answer (score 0):

The first `numList.add("hello");` doesn't compile because all it knows at that point is that `numList` is a `List<? super Number>`. So `numList` can point to anything that is a subtype of `List<? super Number>`, for example, `List<Number>`, and you wouldn't be able to add `"hello"` to a `List<Number>`. Since it might not work for some possible types that `numList` can point to, it cannot allow you to do this.

Now of course, you know that `numList` points to a newly-created `ArrayList`, created with a diamond operator, from a few lines up, and so it should be safe for us to assume that this is an `ArrayList<Object>` for example. But the compiler does not look "a few lines up" -- it must determine whether the statement is legal based on that statement only, and the types of the variables. So it cannot let you do it.

Even if you had assigned an actual `List<Object>` to `numList`, it would still not let you do it:

```
List<Object> objList = new ArrayList<Object>();
List<? super Number> numList = objList;
numList.add("hello"); // does not compile
```

Because again, it only looks at the type of `numList`. The fact that it was assigned from a `List<Object>` is not remembered.

On the other hand, if you had put the element into a `List<Object>`, and then assigned it to the `List<? super Number>`, that would be fine:

```
List<Object> objList = new ArrayList<Object>();
objList.add("hello");
List<? super Number> numList = objList;
```

This is because you are adding it to a `List<Object>`, which is known to be able to take `"hello"`.

Your second piece of code basically does this. It creates a List first (it might be a `List<Object>` or `List<Serializable>`; it doesn't really matter either way), puts the elements in, before then assigning it to the `numList` variable of type `List<? super Number>`.

Basically, when you assign from a more specific type to a more general type, you might not be able to do things with the more general type that you can do with the more specific type.

Answer (score -1):

Arrays.asList doesn't check the type at compile time. You should read about this behavior so that you can understand that you can add anything to this list. However, during compilation, you can obtain the type of Number from this ArrayList, but not String.

Comment: The first part is technically true but irrelevant. The second and third part are simply wrong, you cannot retrieve anything other than an Object from that List. And you can add anything that is a Number into both lists. You are confusing `super` and `extends`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).